# Send JSON to C# MVC, receive empty

Tags: c#, ajax

I am sending a JSON through Ajax to a C# endpoint but it receives it empty, I have tried it with [FromBody] without success.

Javascript:

```
var settings = {
  "url": "Configuracion/CreateTallas",
  "method": "POST",
  "timeout": 0,
  "headers": {
     "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  "data": JSON.stringify({
     "TalTalla": "XXS",
     "TalFechaAlta": "2023-01-13T20:37:53.492Z",
     "TalDescripcion": "Extra Chica",
     "TalEstatus": 1
  }),
};

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
   console.log(response);
});
```

C#:

```
public partial class UntCatTalla
{
    public int TalId { get; set; }

    public string TalTalla { get; set; } = null!;

    public DateTime TalFechaAlta { get; set; }

    public string? TalDescripcion { get; set; }

    public bool TalEstatus { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult CreateTallas(UntCatTalla newTalla)
{
    return Ok(_configs.CreateTallas(newTalla));
}
```

Comment: Is the use of `JSON.stringify` necessary?  What happens if you send the object itself and not a JSON string?

Comment: In the same way it receives it empty.

Comment: Which ASP.NET version are you using? Have you tried camel case property names?

Comment: I am using .Net 6
If I have tried Camel Case and I still have no success.

Answer (score 0):

It is common to use `[FromBody]` attribute if the parameter you want to pass is JSON type.

In your case, you are passing incorrect data which causing the parameter to be empty. Change the value `TalEstatus` to `true` or `false`.

Try below codes

Javascript

```
var settings = {
  "url": "Configuracion/CreateTallas",
  "method": "POST",
  "timeout": 0,
  "headers": {
     "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  "data": JSON.stringify({
     "TalTalla": "XXS",
     "TalFechaAlta": "2023-01-13T20:37:53.492Z",
     "TalDescripcion": "Extra Chica",
     "TalEstatus": true
  }),
};

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
   console.log(response);
});
```

C#

```
public partial class UntCatTalla
{
    public int TalId { get; set; }

    public string TalTalla { get; set; } = null!;

    public DateTime TalFechaAlta { get; set; }

    public string? TalDescripcion { get; set; }

    public bool TalEstatus { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult CreateTallas([FromBody] UntCatTalla newTalla)
{
    return Ok(_configs.CreateTallas(newTalla));
}
```